# Symfony validator

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-validator

My question is related to symfony validator component. I don't use forms. And I want to move validation rules for each entity to separated class (like AuthorVlidator, BookingValidator etc.). How can I move it to separated classes and define rules?

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for [Validation Groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups)

Comment: Simply inject the validation component into your Validator classes and have at it.  No need to get fancy.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you like to move it to separated classes? With annotations it pretty easy to use it.

It's not a good idea to do it, but if you really want to do it in other classes, you could add this method in each classes that you want to validate:

```
class YourObject
{
    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        YourObjectValidator::validate($this, $metadata);
    }
}
```

And:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class YourObjectValidator
{
    public static function validate(YourObject $object, ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('name', new NotBlank());
    }
}
```

If you want separate this logic for add validation depending on properties value, it's not the proper way to do it. You should read the doc, [callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) could be a solution.